# Error with aggregate function in a CASE statement and GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena, redash

I have the following CTE that I am using in a larger query and I receive two different error messages based on how I group.

I am on Redash and using Amazon Athena.  I can group by tenant_id or I can group by `tenant_id` & my case statement that is named `"active"`. Either way I will receive an error.

```sql
active_billpay AS
  (SELECT o.tenant_id as tenant_id, CASE WHEN o.created_date >= min(mbpc.created_date) 
     THEN true else false end as active
    FROM reporting.t_order o
    LEFT JOIN reporting.t_me_bill_pay_charge mbpc ON o.tenant_id = mbpc.tenant_id
      WHERE o.retired_date is null
        AND mbpc.retired_date is null
    GROUP by 1),
```

If I group by only tenant_id:

> Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 13:32: '(CASE WHEN
>   ("o"."created_date" >= "min"("mbpc"."created_date")) THEN true ELSE
>   false END)' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY
>   clause

If I group by both tenant_id and active:

> Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 13:32: GROUP BY clause cannot
>   contain aggregations or window functions:
>   ["min"("mbpc"."created_date")]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to aggregate by `tenant_id` and `created_date`:

```
 SELECT o.tenant_id as tenant_id,
        (CASE WHEN o.created_date >= MIN(mbpc.created_date) THEN true ELSE false
         END) as active
 FROM reporting.t_order o LEFT JOIN
      reporting.t_me_bill_pay_charge mbpc
      ON o.tenant_id = mbpc.tenant_id
 where o.retired_date is null
 and mbpc.retired_date is null
 group by o.tenant_id, o.created_date
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply aggregate functions like `min`, SQL requires you to be very specific about what set of data that aggregate applies to. Even if SQL allowed the query you've written, you'd still only get the minimum `created_date` for each row, not each `tenant_id`.

In order to do what I think you're trying to do, you should use a sub-query to get the minimum `created_date` for each `tenant_id`, then use that value inform your `active` field.

```
SELECT o.tenant_id AS tenant_id,
       CASE WHEN o.created_date >= min_created_date THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS active
FROM   reporting.t_order o
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT tenant_id, MIN (created_date) AS min_created_date
        FROM   reporting.t_me_bill_pay_charge
        WHERE  retired_date IS NULL) mbpc
           ON o.tenant_id = mbpc.tenant_id
WHERE  o.retired_date IS NULL
```

Generally, if you find yourself trying to cheat the SQL syntax requirements by doing something like `group by 1`, that's a strong indication that your approach is flawed.